How can I split this filename to get the date only
How can I use VB.NET to split the below file names with one variable to extract the date portion of the filename?
I'm initially getting the filename from a path. Two examples:
Mozart - Cpt - 03 Aug 2024.xlsx
Mozart - 03 Aug 2024.xlsx
I have this code:
Din Filename as String = ""
Dim mDate as string = format(cdate(split(split(path.getfilename(Filename), "-")(1), ".xlsx")(0)),"yyyy/MM/dd")

The works for the second Mozart - 03 Aug 2024.xlsx example, but not the Mozart - Cpt - 03 Aug 2024.xlsx sample. How can I fix it?

It looks like you want everything after the last -, not the first one.  Something like parts = split(path.getfilename(Filename), "-") then parts(parts.Length - 1)

You want to parse the last - part of the filename (without extension) to Date. So you can use Split and Enumerable.Last and Date.TryParseExact:
Dim lastPart = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Split("-"c).Last()
Date.TryParseExact(lastPart, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, dt)

Complete test code:
Sub Main
    Dim FileNames() As String = {"Mozart - Cpt - 03 Aug 2024.xlsx","Mozart - 03 Aug 2024.xlsx"}
    For Each fileName In FileNames
        Dim lastPart = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName).Split("-"c).Last()
        Dim dt As Date
        If Date.TryParseExact(lastPart, "dd MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, dt)
            Console.WriteLine(dt)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

http://dotnetfiddle.net/sjcWgr
